# Asp.net core identity external providers only

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I want my Asp.net core application to be configured to use external providers only, let's say Facebook only. In other words I don't want my users to have the ability to create an account with a password etc.

How can I modify the default Asp.net core with individual accounts template that is generated by Visual Studio to safely remove such capability of creating local user accounts?

Thanks.

Comment: you could just modify the views for login and registration to remove that

Comment: Yes but I am afraid that some smart user can still be able to play the system and interact with the controllers (which still would work). At the same time I don't know what to erase on those controllers that does not break the external providers functionality or open a security hole

Comment: you could also comment out controller actions in AccountController, if you make a mistake an comment out one that is needed then you can uncomment it

Comment: in my cloudscribe Core project, I have a setting to disable dbauth from the admin  ui this way I could disable local login and register but wait to do it until after social auth is setup https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the `.UseRewriter()` middleware to allow me to redirect to `/Error` for the `Identity` pages that don't apply to my application (I only allow Github authentication and no local registration)

```
public static class IisRewriterConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseIisRewriter(this IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
    {
        using (var iisUrlRewriteStreamReader = File.OpenText("iis-application-route-rewrites.xml"))
        {
            var options = new RewriteOptions()
                .AddIISUrlRewrite(iisUrlRewriteStreamReader);

            applicationBuilder.UseRewriter(options);
        }

        return applicationBuilder;
    }
}
```

Then I call `app.UseIisRewriter();` in `Startup.Configure()`.

My `iis-application-route-rewrites.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect from Identity Forgot Password">
      <match url="^Identity/Account/ForgotPassword" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="Error?id=404" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect from Identity Reset Password">
      <match url="^Identity/Account/ResetPasswordConfirmation" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="Error?id=404" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  <!-- More rules -->
  </rules>
</rewrites>
```

In my `Login.cshtml.cs` I removed all the request handlers that I no longer wanted users to have access to.